# Can you programatically create an expression when setting a property in WSO2?

Tags: json, dynamic, properties, wso2, expression

I have the a case where we accept 'JSON'-like code into an API, there is a problem with one case, where a customer has a numeric ID as a fieldname.

eg.

```
{
  "Node1": {
     "123456": [
        {
         "Field1": "Value1",
         "Field2": "Value2"
        },
        {
         "Field1": "Value3",
         "Field2": "Value4"
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

Now, trying to set the array to a property works if I hardcode in 123456

```
<property name="fields" expression="json-eval($.Node1.123456)" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
```

but I need somehow to dynamically set this expression. I have a reference to the id in question as a property value.

Is it possible to dynamically construct an expression so I can set this json as a property?

ie. something like

```
 <property name="myid" value="123456"/>
 <property name="fields" expression="fn:concat('json-eval($.Node1.', get-property('myid'))" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
```

Could it be done converting the message to XML and somehow referencing it there and converting back to json?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using Property Mediator with [Script Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Script+Mediator).

Here is an example:

```
 <property name="payload" expression="json-eval($.)"/>
 <property name="myid" value="123456"/>
 <property name="HARDCODED" value="none"/>
 <script language="js">

    var myid = mc.getProperty("myid");

    // you can interate your payload if needed
    var payload = mc.getProperty("payload");

    // Or just make a String of it  
    var json = '{ "Node1" : { "' + myid + '": [{ "Field1": "Value1", "Field2": "Value2" }] } }';

     mc.setProperty("HARDCODED", json);

 </script>
 <payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>$1</format>
    <args>
       <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('HARDCODED')"/>
    </args>
 </payloadFactory>
```

With JavaScript you can go right to it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Thiago, this is ok for creating the json, but I'm looking to assign a json value to a property.. ie. that id 123456 is dynamic, trying to set a property using 123456 doesn't seem to be possible. You can't construct the json-eval using a dynamic property (like 'expression="fn:concat('json-eval($.Node1.', get-property('myid'))" )'

Comment: No problem @Brian, but you really need the json-eval? Why not to use a property mediator?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this through a roundabout way. I had to modify the message after it arrived using my own Mediator..

In the code below, I'm just taking the 1st occurance as an example

```
public class MyMediator extends AbstractMediator { 
  .
  .
  public boolean mediate(MessageContext mc) {
    OMFactory factory = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();

    SOAPBody b = mc.getEnvelope().getBody();
    Iterator it = b.getFirstElement().getChildrenWithLocalName("Node1");
    if(it.hasNext()){
        OMElement obj = (OMElement)it.next();
        Iterator w_it = obj.getChildElements();
        if(w_it.hasNext()){
            OMElement cfield = (OMElement)w_it.next();
            cfield.setLocalName("Order");
            .
            .
        }
       ((OMContainerEx)b).setFirstChild(obj);
     }
  }
  .
  .    
}
```

I could then get the id and create a new OMElement with the ID and rename the element something meaningful like 'Order'

So now I can reference this using a json path and set it as a property
eg.

```
<property name="fields" expression="json-eval($.Order)" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
```

In my case, the id is also in the fields of the Order .. so it's not an issue for me, but if you needed to, when you are renaming the node, you could store the existing name (ie. 12345) as a value by creating a new OMElement and adding it to your obj

the '((OMContainerEx)b).setFirstChild(obj);' is optional .. I didn't care for the previous paths so just dropped them.

Hope this helps someone (or someone comes back with a better idea ;) )

Comment: Just fyi.. not marking it as the accepted answer since to my knowledge, you can still NOT programmatically create an expression when assigning a property. This work around just suites my specific case.